# conditionally replacing values in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe, where the 2nd, 3rd and 6th columns look like so:

| start | end | strand |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 108286 | 108361 | + |
| 734546 | 734621 | - |
| 761233 | 761309 | + |

I'm trying to implement a conditional where, if strand is +, then the value in end becomes the equivalent value in start + 1, and if strand is -, then the value in start becomes the value in end, so the output should look like this:

| start | end | strand |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 108286 | 108287 | + |
| 734620 | 734621 | - |
| 761233 | 761234 | + |

And where the pseudocode may look like this:

```
if df["strand"] == "+": 
        df["end"] = df["start"] + 1
        
else:
        df["start"] = df["end"] - 1
```

I imagine this might be best done with `loc/iloc` or `numpy.where`? but I can't seem to get it to work, as always, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, `loc` is the operator you are looking for

```
df.loc[df.strand=='+','end'] = df.loc[df.strand=='+','start']+1
df.loc[df.strand=='-','start'] = df.loc[df.strand=='-','end']-1
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use `numpy.where`:

```
import numpy as np
df[['start', 'end']] = np.where(df[['strand']]=='-', df[['end','end']]-[1,0], df[['start','start']]+[0,1])
```

Note that this assumes `strand` can have one of two values: `+` or `-`. If it can have any other values, we can use `numpy.select` instead.

Output:

```
    start     end strand
0  108286  108287      +
1  734620  734621      -
2  761233  761234      +
```